# Read certificate store of a server

Tags: c#, server, certificate, store, x509

I am trying to read the certificate stores of different servers.

I need to login to an admin user and access the server to read the certificate store. I cant find any other possibilities than the X509Store class to read a certificate store (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store?view=netcore-3.1) but i cant figure out a possibility to login to a specific user with this class. I'm also not sure if it is possible to connect to a server with this class.

Maybe you can help me to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: Look at store location at following page which give an example of getting all users. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.policy.policylevel?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't easily read other users certificate stores using X509Store. You have to setup impersonated logon session and run the code inside this session. See [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8) method for an example of how this can be achieved.